# Netbeans: how to change the default tool which opens .txt file?

Tags: netbeans, text-editor

I was living in peace and netbeans used to open text files in the netbeans editor. Then one fine day I wanted to open 1 of the text files in a web browser (to render some html, and I didn't want the headache of making a new html file. Yup, yup, I know I was being a fool). So I right clicked the file from inside netbeans and chose an 'open as' option and used treat file as "html/text" expecting it will open in the browser. And to my surprise the browser did come up and tried opening the file. But then all the text files now always open the browser and none of them get opened in the netbeans editor, no matter how hard I try, and netbeans no longer shows the 'open as' option when right clicking the text files.

Can some one suggest some way to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try going to Tools->Options then click Miscellaneous and then the files 
tab. There should be an associations editor you can use to change this.